# Youtube API Put request to update metadata acting as readonly

Tags: jquery, ajax, youtube-api, metadata, put

Ok, so I've given up on attempting to update metadata via the onApiReady for the Youtube API and moved on to issuing a put request as indicated by https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/update.

The ajax request returns successful, but no data is actually updated.  Additionally the jqXHR that is returned details the original data before the update request is made.  I've transformed it into a sample for demonstration purposes, but it still doesn't work.  Here is the put request.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/?part=snippet&key=<replaced with api key>",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + oAuthToken.access_token
        },
        data: $.parseJSON('{"id": "<replaced with videoId>", "snippet": {"title": "New Title", "description": "New Description"}, "status": {"privacyStatus": "unlisted"}}'),
        success: function(data, error, completeError) {
            alert("Hallelujah");
        }
    });
```

It reports as successful yet, no data is updated on youtube and the snippet that is returned in the response contains all of the original values.

My OAuth2 token is authenticated against
    `var scopes = ['https://gdata.youtube.com', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner', 'http://gdata.youtube.com', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'];`

I've been around and around with this, and I know that either Youtube can't actually do this (not likely) or I'm missing something stupid and simple.  If anyone can help, let me know.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer:

[How to update video on YouTube using API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469782/how-to-update-video-on-youtube-using-api-v3)

I believe that you must specify the kind of the resource:

"kind": "youtube#video",

Comment: This looks like it would work, but I figured out in the end how to do it via the onApiReady call after I discovered that using the iframe directly interferes with its firing and changing to use the div.  Thanks for the advice.